# R Shiny debugging - finding an error that doesn't have a file and line number reference

Tags: r, shiny

How can I find the location of an error in R Shiny without a file or line reference?  The message is

```
Warning: Error in : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I've tried setting

```
options(shiny.error = browser)
```

which stops at the error and opens a new tab in RStudio called [Anonymous function] which doesn't look like any of my code.  With the browser active, is there a way to find out what line of code was just run or some other way to find out where the error occurred?

Comment: you are most likely trying to index a reactive value without 'resolving' it. Check if you have `my_reactive_value[[1]]` or similar that is missing the `()`

Comment: that seems reasonable however in this case it was something else - I did (after a long time) find out that the problem was nested outputs, i.e. output$my_ui <- renderUI({ output$my_ui <- renderUI({.. Oddly the app still worked even with the error message.